# interacting with ADFS, azure ACS

Tags: adfs

Is this possible or I'm going totally wrong?

Consider we have this situation:
One web site (web1) hosted on one server, and another one hosted on different server (lets say web2). Both of these application have login/register. 
Now i want to allow users from web2 access to web1. For example like this, user who is registered on web2 goes to web1 site and tries to login with username: "web2/username" and password: "somePassword". Now my web1 application needs to check if that user exists in web2 lists of users.

Now i managed to make something with Azure ACS(loging in with Google/live account), but i do not want to use ACS. What i want is that my app interacts with web2 ADFS ( im not sure if this is possible or even if ADFS can be used in this way) and finds out if user that tries to login on web1 is actually registered on web2.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: thanks, and sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. This is the basic "Single Sign On" scenario. Both websites will rely on an an "STS" to authenticate users. ADFS and ACS are examples of "STSs".

An STS is usually an entity on its own. It doesn't belong to web1 or web2. The library to use on the web sites (assuming .NET based apps) is WIF (Windows Identity Foundation), that will handle all authentication requests and token parsing for you.

You can use ADFS, but the all your users will have to authenticate against Active Directory.

I'd suggest you read [this introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359108.aspx) and this [chapter on SSO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359102.aspx).

Comment: But can i just check if user exists? and not send them to their login page to authenticate?

Comment: Or authenticate that user just from code, ex. he provides his username and pw, and i authenticate him without prompting to ADFS login page.

Comment: I tried with sample code from here 
http://leandrob.com/2012/04/requesting-a-token-from-adfs-2-0-using-ws-trust-with-username-and-password/
now im getting this error: "ID3082: The request scope is not valid or is unsupported". Question: when configuring ADFS, do i need to configure it on both servers? Or can i just configure it on one server, and from another interact with it just from c# ( for example code from that link). If yes, how can i configure it?